# Hey guys! I'm working on a react app and I want to have the users go directly to login screen rather than home but I can't seems to do it, any tips?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here is my app.js, I want to have the users go directly to /auth rather than /home when they access the site and after they login, they would be taken to home

```
return (
      <Grid
        container
        direction="column"
        className={classes.app}>

        <Header />
        <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.body}>
          <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/auth" component={withAuthenticator(MyAuth)} />
            <Route path="/user" component={withAuthenticator(User)} />
            <Route path="/product" component={withAuthenticator(Product)} /
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.footer}>
          <Footer />
        </Grid>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First solution will be to use **render** method inside **Route**. Just check if use is Authed show Home page, if it is not show Login page.
   Route will look like this:

   ```
    <Switch>
            <Route path="/" render={()=> isAuthed ? <Home/> : <Login/>} />
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/auth" component={withAuthenticator(MyAuth)} />
            <Route path="/user" component={withAuthenticator(User)} />
            <Route path="/product" component={withAuthenticator(Product)} /
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
   ```
2. Second solution. It to use condition inside `<Home/>` component.

**Home.js**

```
const Home = ()=> {
   useEffect(()=>{
       isAuthed && <Redirect to="/login" />
     },[])

  return(....)

}
```

**Route will like this**

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route from="/login"component={Login} />
    <Route path="/auth" component={withAuthenticator(MyAuth)} />
    <Route path="/user" component={withAuthenticator(User)} />
    <Route path="/product" component={withAuthenticator(Product)} /
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem like this in my projects... First, you need to have a component that I usually called it PrivateRote and this is how it looks (you could see the complete explanation of how this works [here](https://ui.dev/react-router-v5-protected-routes-authentication/). I learned this solution in that article but there is more on the web you could search for it:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    const authenticated = useSelector(state=> state.auth.login.authenticated);
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => authenticated === true
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}}/>
            }
        />
    )
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

this is HOC that takes care of show or hide your component if the route you are trying to get is private or not. Then you just need to use it in your routes file like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import TurnosCreatePage from "../views/TurnosCreatePage";
import TurnosListPage from "../views/TurnosListPage";
import PrivateRoute from "./Routes Component/PrivateRoute";

export default [
  <PrivateRoute path="/turnos/create" component={TurnosCreatePage} exact key="create" />, //this is a private route example
  <Route path="/turnos/list/:id" component={TurnosListPage} key="list" />, //this a public route example
];
```

then you just need to import your route file in your app.js like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './views/Home';
import NotFoundPage from './components/Errors/NotFoundPage';

//Import your Routes here
import turnoRoutes from './routes/turno';

const App = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={Home} strict={true} exact={true} key="home" />
                {turnoRoutes}
                <Route component={NotFoundPage} key="notfound" />
            </Switch>
        </>
    )
};

export default App;
```

I hope this could help you! Feel free to ask any doubt!